# Is it secure to store custom cookie in memory

Tags: java, security, caching, cookies

Let say the application does not use JSESSION but uses a custom CSESSION for cookies.

Is it safe to store the custom CSESSION cookie in memory of the JAVA Application?

the issue I see is that in case of memory dump of the application the sessions will be leaked.

I would like to know if there are better practices to secure these or do we accept this risk as there are alternate controls to prevent memory dump.

Comment: What application? Are referring to a java servlet? In what way is the CSESSION cookie more sensible then the JSESSION cookie? The content of the JSESSION cookie in a java servlet is the session id. The session ID is stored in memory and is available always to the application (request.getSession().getId()....). Why is the session ID a sensible information that may leak? Why does somebody need to have the session ID to access sensible information, if it already is able to do a memory dump?

Comment: It is very similar to JSession. I can hijack a session if I know the session ID. I agree to the fact that if you can do  memory dump you can leak information. I am trying to find if there are standards around this.